# Clojure STM: non consistent remove

Tags: concurrency, clojure, transactions, stm

Consider a very simple hashtable, with the following structure:

```
(defn make-hashtable
  [cap]
  (let 
    [tablesize (int (Math/ceil (* cap 1.30)))]
      {:tablesize tablesize
     :capacity cap
       :size (ref 0)
       :vector (vec (map (fn [_] (ref '())) (range tablesize)))
       :type :hashtable}))
```

I have the basic operations for it, such as `put`, `get` and `remove`. I wrote some tests to test them in parallel using `pcalls`. As I first developed a test that runs on one "`thread`", (ie just using one function to call `pcalls`) and it succeeds, I must assume the problem is not there but in the `remove`function not being thread-safe.

The remove is implemented as follows:

```
(defn mht-remove
  [table key]
  (let [pos (table-pos table key)]
    (dosync 
      (let [bucket @((:vector table) pos)]
        (ensure (:size table))
        (ensure ((:vector table) pos))
        (defn equalskey?
          [x]
          (= (:key x) key))
        (when (some equalskey? bucket)
            (ref-set ((:vector table) pos) (remove equalskey? bucket))
            (alter (:size table) dec))))))
```

The odd thing is, that it even happens that a bucket of just one element didn't get removed. Which is odd, since only the elements of the vector are refs, not the whole vector.
**Question: Why is this code not thread-safe, what am I potentially doing wrong?**

---

**Note:** I know many will try to comment on the design of this application, but this is **not** the kind of answer I am interested in. I want to understand clojure's STM rather than writing pure functional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't do `def` or `defn` inside a `dosync`block since it is a global side-effect, and thus messes with your transactions. Even though I don't fully understand, except that according to the documentation side-effects are not allowed, this is what messes up everything.

Thanks to the guys on Freenode's `#clojure`

Comment: More than that: don't use `def` or `defn` inside a function at all, period. It will mess up your single-threaded code as well, even without a `dosync`.

Comment: Use 'let' instead of 'def': clojure fns are values so you can assign them to a temporary binding.